# How to git know if a file is staged or commited?

Tags: git

The git `index` file stores the hash of the file, filename along with [other metadata](https://github.com/git/git/blob/867b1c1bf68363bcfd17667d6d4b9031fa6a1300/Documentation/technical/index-format.txt#L38) such as created date and modified date.
When we do `git status` how does git knows whether the file which already exists in the index is staged or committed since it stores hash of the file for both staged and commited files?

So how does git differentiate between staged and commited files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When we do `git status` how does git knows whether the file which already exists in the index is staged or committed since it stores hash of the file for both staged and commited files?

This question fundamentally doesn't make sense.  I think you're imagining Git is doing something that Git doesn't actually do.

As the documentation you linked notes, each index entry holds:

- the file's full name (`path/to/file.ext`, but with compression depending on the index format);
- the file's "mode" (`100644` or `100755` for files, `120000` for symbolic links, and `160000` for gitlinks—these entries are never tree objects so `040000` simply never appears<sup>1</sup>);
- the staging number (0 to 3);
- the hash ID of the file's content; and
- the cache data.

That's what you see from `git ls-files --stage` and `git ls-files --debug`:

```
100644 2b9a0a4e22fa5256575b6b184a16fc93ee47869e 0       compat/inet_pton.c
100644 bc2f9382a17f8f63a783680770a46358964e8f81 0       compat/linux/procinfo.c
100644 56bcb4277f47c295993c853a84edfe45e6aa3911 0       compat/memmem.c
100644 2607de93af594034413e4512c4d7dd33fb133023 0       compat/mingw.c
```

for instance.

Git's index holds one<sup>2</sup> of these entries *for every file that will be in the next commit*.  These are the "staged" files.  That's all there is: the index holds the *proposed next commit*.  The `git add` and `git rm` commands work by updating the proposed next commit, by changing what's in the index.

When you run `git status`, Git:

- Reads the *current commit*.  The current commit has a commit hash ID, which Git finds by reading `HEAD`, which either contains the hash ID directly, or contains the name of the *current branch*.  If `HEAD` contains a branch name, Git reads the branch name's value to find the current commit hash ID.<sup>3</sup>
- Reads the *index*.

The current commit's tree—the saved tree object that goes with the commit—plus the files in the index, tell Git which files match the *current commit:* that is, which files in the index are also in the current commit, and vice versa, whose hash IDs match.  The proposed next commit and the *current* commit match, so Git won't bother saying anything *about* these files.  But they will still be in the next commit, if and when you make one.

For files that have *different* hash IDs, or files that no longer exist or are new, `git status` will tell you that these files are *staged for commit* (and/or are new or are staged to be deleted).  So that's where you see the *staged for commit* stuff: any index entry, e.g., that for `compat/memmem.c`, if its hash ID *doesn't* match the hash ID in the *current commit's tree*, then `compat/memmem.c` is "staged for commit".

**Note that this is the same information that you'd get for a `git diff --name-status` that compares `HEAD` vs the index.**<sup>4</sup>  So the *staged for commit* part is just the output of `git diff`, reformatted a bit.

Having figured out what to tell you is "staged for commit", `git status` now goes on to do a *second* `git diff`.  This time, it diffs the index files vs the working-tree files.<sup>5</sup>  Once again, for every file that *is* in the index, but *isn't* in the working tree or *has different content* in the working tree, Git will say something about it, under the *not staged for commit* grouping.  This particular diff is a little different for two reasons:

- Git can't *just* compare hash IDs.  Git needs to use the index hash ID to expand the file contents out, and compare that to the actual file contents.  But Git can use the cache data *in* the index to rapidly skip over files that it can prove have not been changed.  (For cases where it *can't* skip, `git status` here can be very slow.  Git is full of special-case optimizations to take advantage of as many "can skip because _____ (fill in the blank)" cases as anyone's found so far, and it's constantly growing new ones, like the file system monitor stuff.)
- When Git reads the working tree (laboriously if necessary—again, Git tries to cheat and skip work if possible here), and comes across a non-ignored file that *isn't* in the index, this file is grouped into a special category.

The special category of "file in working tree not in index and not marked ignore" logically *should* show up in `git diff --name-status` as status `A`, or "added", but in fact `git diff` just doesn't say anything at all. here  To make `git status` more useful than plain `git diff`, `git status` collects these names up and then describes them as *untracked files*.  The untracked files listing output will compress an entire directory's worth of untracked files as `dir/` instead of listing every file, if it's allowed to do so.

---

<sup>1</sup>If you try to jam one in somehow, and the attempt isn't rejected outright, the mode mysteriously changes into `160000`.  This is arguably a bug: if the index *could* hold `040000` entries, we could commit empty directories.  See also [How do I add an empty directory to a Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/115983/1256452)

<sup>2</sup>When the staging number is nonzero, Git's index holds up to three entries per file, but you aren't allowed to run `git commit` at this point.  The nonzero-stage entries represent a "conflicted file".  You must "resolve the conflict" and run `git add`, which will update the index so that the nonzero-stage entries are gone and there's only one stage-zero entry recording the resolved-conflict-file content.  (Or, you can `git rm` the whole thing so that there's no entry at all, meaning the next commit won't have the file.)

<sup>3</sup>In the slightly peculiar case of an *unborn* or *orphan* branch—Git uses these terms more or less interchangeably—`HEAD` holds the name of a branch that doesn't exist.  An attempt to read the value of that branch name produces an internal "does not exist" error, which Git handles by saying to itself: oh, *an unborn branch!*  To make things easier for the rest of Git, Git immediately pretends that the current commit's *tree* is the [empty tree](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9765453/1256452), so that the remainder of the code doesn't need a special case: by using the empty tree as the current commit's tree, all the files appear to be new files.

<sup>4</sup>You can get this with `git diff --name-status --cached` or `git diff --name-status --staged`.  The `--cached` and `--staged` options here are pure synonyms.  (A lot of Git commands now use either option, to help stop using the ancient name *cache* for the index / staging-area.  Some Git commands still only have `--cached` as an option though, e.g., `git rm`.)

<sup>5</sup>This diff is the one you get with a plain `git diff`, e.g., `git diff --name-status`, but note the special casing for "untracked" files here: this kind of `git diff` doesn't bother to mention untracked files at all, while `git status` does.

---

#### Review / TL;DR version

> When we do `git status` how does git knows whether the file which already exists in the index is staged or committed ...

Everything in the *current commit* is committed.  The commit's contents are there, stored in the commit, permanently (well, mostly-permanently<sup>6</sup>) and quite read-only.  Git *needs* the hash ID of the current commit to find that commit and thence to see what's *in* the current commit, but Git is easily able to *find* that hash ID by reading `HEAD`.

Meanwhile, whatever's in the staging area is staged.  That includes files that *haven't* changed since `git switch` or `git checkout` initially *filled the index from the current commit*.  So `git switch somebranch` has filled the index and all the files match,<sup>7</sup> and if you have't futzed with the index since then, `git status` doesn't *say* anything, even though every file is staged.

---

<sup>6</sup>A commit that literally can't be found, so that you aren't sure if it even exists, might eventually go away and stop existing.  How and when are outside the scope of this answer.  If you can see the commit with `git log` or `git log --all`, it's still there for sure, though.

<sup>7</sup>If you have staged and/or unstaged changes that `git status` reports *and* you run `git checkout` or `git switch` **and it succeeds**—it might fail—then the switch deliberately *did not update some file(s)*.  As a simple overview, the setup is kind of obvious: every commit stores *de-duplicated* files, via the hash ID trick, so if we're moving from commit `a123456` to `b789abc` and most of the files are the same, the switching doesn't have to ream out those files in the first place.  But because index and working tree can be modified or not-modified *separately*, this actually gets pretty hairy.  See [Checkout another branch when there are uncommitted changes on the current branch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22053757/1256452) for the gory details.

Answer (score 1):

When tracked files in Git are changed and added to the staging area, all the objects in your staging area form a 'tree' object that collectively defines all the changes you've made to the repository. This information is stored in the `index` file. Yes.

When you perform a `commit` a commit object is created, which contains a reference to the 'tree' object in the staging area (which contains all of your changes).

Git can simply know which file is staged/committed by checking if the file exists in a tree that no `commit` object points to (new file) or if the file object hash changed compared to the one in the existing tree (updated file). This means the file hasn't been committed. Once you perform the commit, the file moves away from the staging area, because it now comes under a tree, which is pointed at by a `commit` object.

At the heart of it, is the usage of hashes to determine difference between files, coupled with the 'tree' mechanism.

You can read more about internals of Git in the official book. [Here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Plumbing-and-Porcelain) is the chapter on internals.

Comment: Technically, the staging area only holds entries for the files, not trees. (Though technically, the index *can* hold cached tree entries too—but they're just cached for speed reasons, not part of the defining data.)